# How do you display vertical, end of page print margin guides?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I can't seem to figure out how to display vertical, end of page print margin guides. I use these in Eclipse to make sure my code doesn't run off the page. Is there any way to enable a similar feature in Visual Studio? Is there a plugin that will do this for me? Thanks!

Seen here on the right: http://lukemiller.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/80column_line.png

Answer (score 5):

For others with a similar problem I managed to find a solution:

Visual Studio 2015 -> Tools -> Extensions and Updates... -> Online -> search for Paul Harrington's Editor Guidelines extension.